# What is the difference between RealModelType and ModelType on ModelBindingContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on writing a custom model binder which handles a variety of different object types, and we're looking for the best way to determine type of the incoming object. However, on ModelBindingContext we have both ModelType and RealModelType, and googling hasn't found anything that tells me what exactly is the difference between the two.

Comment: Not clear what your asking. The [ModelBindingContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbindingcontext(v=vs.118).aspx) only contains a property named `ModelType` (not `RealModelType`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke In a running project though, `ModelBindingContext` showed a `RealModelType` member. To see this, you'd have to set up a project and make a class that inherits from `DefaultModelBinder`, override the `CreateModel(ControllerContext, ModelBindingContext, Type)` function and break inside the function. That said, my coworker and I just tried to reproduce it and haven't been able to, so it might have just been a bug in our code.